# Default WiFi port value in android

Tags: android, wifi, port, android-wifi, wifi-direct

For sending file from one device to another we need server socket and a socket of same port on both sides.I would like to send a file to someone who is not using my app.In this case I managed to connect two devices through WiFi direct but I am not able to send files as I do not know the port value for socket

Comment: You *set* the socket yourself. You could use NSD to discover the devices.

Comment: There is no built-in support for file transfer in "Android" so there is no standard port for that use.  Anything you manage to accomplish will be based on having compatible apps installed on both devices, and so those apps will be what select the port within the unprivileged range.